# C# Instagram: Getting list of Follows is returning blank

Tags: c#, json, instagram, instagram-api

I'm new to Instagram API, still trying to figure out by trial & error. I've gone through the documentation and implemented the code in C#. Currently I'm successfully able to achieve access token by showing authorization web page in a Web Browser control, and using the access token I can obtain the user's basic detail.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=XXX&response_type=token&scope=follower_list
```

My objective is to obtain list of Follows for the authorized user. For this I've included the required scope in the authorization URL, and user has allowed permission to the app for reading Follows list. To get list of Follows for authorized user, I use the following URL in a WebClient to download the result:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=XXX
```

This is resulting me blank JSON data as follows:

```
{
    "pagination":{
        },
    "meta":{
        "code":200},
    "data":[]
}
```

Anyone has a clue what's going on here or what am I missing? API documentation seems pretty straight so I'm not sure what's missing.

IMPORTANT: My app is still in sandbox mode. I'm not sure if that might be causing a problem. The documentation says I can still have access to my own account even in sandbox mode. So this shouldn't have blocked the results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sandbox mode, it will only return users that are in your approved sandbox user list.

Add one of the user you follow to the sandbox and it will show up in the API response.

Comment: Since I created this app and registered with Instagram, so I'm already the admin and in the list of sandbox users list.

Comment: correct, but the users you follow are not in sandbox, add one of the user you follow to sandbox, then only that will show in API response

Comment: Okay. Now I get it. Thanks, I'll try it out.